# How to add stripe payment gateway into an android studio app?

Tags: java, android-studio, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I want to add a stripe payment gateway in my app but could not found any complete solution please someone help me how do I create a complete payment system using stripe payment gateway in my android studio java app

Answer (score 0):

You would use the pre-built PaymentSheet integration, or the CardInputWidget integration, to integrate Stripe into your Android app: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android